# Couting Moves made for Puzzle [COCOS2D]

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Im back again sorry! :)

Just need a quick hand if possible, i want to be able to count the number of moves that are made in this slider puzzle that im building. What ive done so far is:

.h

```
int moves;
CCLabel *moveLabel;
```

.m

```
moveLabel = [[CCLabel labelWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Moves: %d", moves] dimensions: CGSizeMake(130, 27) alignment: UITextAlignmentRight fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize: 25.0] retain]; 
    moveLabel.position = ccp(55,430); 
    [self schedule: @selector(tick3:) interval:1.0];
[self addChild: moveLabel];
```

The method that deals with the swapping of the tiles is this, so i added moves++; to it at the bottom:

```
-(void) changeWithTileA: (Tile *) a TileB: (Tile *) b sel : (SEL) sel{
    CCAction *actionA = [CCSequence actions:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:kMoveTileTime position:[b pixPosition]], [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:sel data: a], nil];

    CCAction *actionB = [CCSequence actions:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:kMoveTileTime position:[a pixPosition]], [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:sel data: b], nil];
    [a.sprite runAction:actionA];
    [b.sprite runAction:actionB];

    [a trade:b];

    moves++;
}
```

Im not sure if this is the correct way to do it, or how to reference that method here:

```
[self schedule: @selector(   ) interval:1.0];
```

If anyone could help that would be great :)

Cheers

Comment: Are you able to add in a bit more explanation of what you're trying to do? I'm a bit confused at the moment about your objective is and what isn't working.

Comment: Im doing a slider puzzle which loads a scrambled image and you have to move the tiles to put all the pieces back into the correct place. What i want to do is count everytime the user moves 2 tiles. Thats where the 'changewithtileA' method comes in, thats what switches the tiles. All i want to do is have a label where it counts how many moves it takes for the user to complete the puzzle

Comment: The swapping of tiles works, right? So what isn't working? And what's the tick3 method that you're calling in the second code block?

Comment: Yes everything works ok, i just want to count the amount of times the tiles have been swapped. The tick3: doesnt do anything thats where i was struggling, im not sure how to call this method: `-(void) changeWithTileA: (Tile *) a TileB: (Tile *) b sel : (SEL) sel` where ive set my label so that moves++ increases. `[self schedule: @selector(HERE) interval:1.0];
`

Answer (score 0):

You need something that updates the label. You can have changeWithTileA do this directly, or you could have changeWithTileA call NSNotificationCenter and have a separate method that listens for the notification and updates the label's text. The latter is the better way if you ever intend to have something else happen whenever the move count changes.

The code to do the update is:

```
[moveLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Moves: %d", moves]];
```

However, note that the [reference](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0/interface_c_c_label_atlas.html) says that setString is a slow operation and recommends using CCLabelAtlas instead of CCLabel.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly, i just added your code above and removed this line all together: `[self schedule: @selector(changeWithTileA:) interval:1.0];`